# Send ctrl+alt+numpad2 from Linux to a Windows 8.1 via rdesktop

Tags: linux, windows-8.1, keyboard-shortcuts, remote-desktop, rdesktop

How to send this combination without using the Virtual Keyboard on Windows?
I've already tried to toggle fullscreen on an off, and -K option do grab or do not grab keybindings, and -N to sync numlock between local and remote.. I've also been looking for those microsoft remote desktop keyboard shortcuts like ctrl+alt+end equals ctrl+alt+delete, bot do not have some to ctrl+alt+some_numpad.

ctrl+alt+del, Alt+tab, ctrl+esc, super, ctrl+c, ctrl+v, alt+f4, all those works fine for example... only ctrl+alt+some_numpad_number is that do not works anyway.

It works fine if emulating via Virtual Keyboard, but I would like to know how to use my own keyboard for that.

Thanks.

Comment: Switched to vncserver/vncviewer with:

$ echo "Vncviewer*grabKeyboard: true" >> ~/.Xresources
$ xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources
$ vncviewer -fullscreen win8.1_ip_addr

Comment: You should post that as a full answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switched to vncserver/vncviewer with:

```
echo "Vncviewer*grabKeyboard: true" >> ~/.Xresources
xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources
vncviewer -fullscreen win8.1_ip_addr
```